# Pyinstaller can't find module TkTreeCtrl

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a program that makes use of the MultiListView from TkTreeCtrl which I'm trying to compile into an executable file using pyinstaller. I'm able to create the executable file and run it, however as soon as it gets to the initialization of the MultiListView it throws up a window that says "Failed to execute script app". How can I get pyinstaller to recognize MultiListView? TkTreeCtrl is unable to be installed via pip, it required putting the folder in my directory and running setup.py.

I've tried searching for a "hook" file online to allow pyinstaller to find the module, I can't seem to find one. I've also tried --hidden-import=tkinter as I've seen that suggested but can't decipher what it's supposed to do. It does the same thing with or without being compiled as a single file. I used a logger and guaranteed that it's on the line where the MultiListBox is created that the program crashes. If it needs stating, I can launch the python file using the command line just fine on my computer.

I use pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Scripts/JobMaintainer/app.py in Command Line to compile the program

Expected: A Google search would result in a hook file that I could attach to my pyinstall which would allow TkTreeCtrl to be added to my executable file

Actual: Until I find some sort of solution, TkTreeCtrl causes it to be impossible to create an executable file from a python script.